# SQL Performance using a COALESCE Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query with a join between several tables.

When I run this query it takes 1min 12 however if I add a Coalesce around the accountID I get a massive performace benefit and it runs in 12 minutes. See the full unedited query below.

```
    SELECT dbo.CaptionMapItem.CaptionMapItemID, 
       dbo.CaptionMapItem.NodeText, 
       CaptionMapItem_1.NodeText AS 'Level1_Caption', 
       CaptionMapItem_2.NodeText AS 'Level2_Caption', 
       dbo.Account.Account, 
       SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 4 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'USD_Total',
       SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 5 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'GBP_Total',
       SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 6 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'CAD_Total',
       SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 7 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'EUR_Total' 
  FROM dbo.CaptionMapItem 
       INNER JOIN dbo.CaptionMapItem AS CaptionMapItem_1 
          ON dbo.CaptionMapItem.CaptionMapItemID = CaptionMapItem_1.ParentID 
       INNER JOIN dbo.CaptionMapItem AS CaptionMapItem_2 
          ON CaptionMapItem_1.CaptionMapItemID = CaptionMapItem_2.ParentID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount 
         ON CaptionMapItem_2.CaptionMapItemID = dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount.CaptionMapItemID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Account 
         ON dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount.AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tx 
         ON dbo.Account.AccountID = dbo.Tx.CreditAccountID 
 GROUP BY dbo.CaptionMapItem.CaptionMapItemID, 
          dbo.CaptionMapItem.NodeText, 
          CaptionMapItem_1.NodeText, 
          CaptionMapItem_2.NodeText, 
          dbo.Account.Account 
HAVING dbo.CaptionMapItem.NodeText LIKE '%CashFLow%'
```

Upon running through query analyser it added a coalesce around the accountID join. However it also reduces much quicker when the coalesce is on any join.

Comment: ouch! _LIKE '%CashFLow%'_ this will hurt the query.  move it from the HAVING to the WHERE, it may help, since you eliminate the rows you don't want before you try to group them.

Comment: Cheers, i have tried that and it came in at around 12 secs aslong as i still have the coalesce function on the join

Comment: Slightly confused -- you say the query takes "1 min 12" but adding a coasece gives you a perf benefit and it runs in 12 minutes ... ? Should this be seconds? That aside, have you tried looking at the execution plan for the query?

Comment: In SQL-92 COALESCE is an *expression* but BOL uses the term 'function' so I won't mark you down ;)

Comment: Sorry, it should have been 12secs. I had a look at the execution plan but still non the wiser why the coalesce made such a difference. THanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping `dbo.Account.AccountID` into `COALESCE`, you make the condition unsargable.

`SQL Server` cannot use nested loops with an index seek on `dbo.Account.AccountID` anymore and it switches to the index scan with `MERGE JOIN` or `HASH JOIN` instead.

**Update:**

Assuming your `CaptionMapItem` and `CaptionMapItemAccount` are key-preserved, try this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  dbo.CaptionMapItem.CaptionMapItemID, 
                dbo.CaptionMapItem.NodeText, 
                CaptionMapItem_1.NodeText AS 'Level1_Caption', 
                CaptionMapItem_2.NodeText AS 'Level2_Caption',
                AccountID
        FROM    dbo.CaptionMapItem 
        JOIN    dbo.CaptionMapItem AS CaptionMapItem_1 
        ON      dbo.CaptionMapItem.CaptionMapItemID = CaptionMapItem_1.ParentID 
        JOIN    dbo.CaptionMapItem AS CaptionMapItem_2 
        ON      CaptionMapItem_1.CaptionMapItemID = CaptionMapItem_2.ParentID 
        LEFT JOIN
                dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount
        ON      CaptionMapItem_2.CaptionMapItemID = dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount.CaptionMapItemID 
        LEFT JOIN
                dbo.Account 
        ON      dbo.CaptionMapItemAccount.AccountID = dbo.Account.AccountID 
        WHERE   dbo.CaptionMapItem.NodeText LIKE '%CashFLow%'
        ) qA
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 4 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'USD_Total',
                SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 5 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'GBP_Total',
                SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 6 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'CAD_Total',
                SUM(CASE Tx.CurrencyID WHEN 7 THEN dbo.Tx.AmountGross END) AS 'EUR_Total'
        FROM    dbo.Tx 
        WHERE   dbo.Tx.CreditAccountID = qA.AccountID
        ) qTX
```

Comment: thanks, would we be able to replace the COALESCE with any funtion? I tried wrapping the join with isNull() and it again took 1m 12secs.

Does it only work for coalesce and not other functions?

Comment: `@Stephen`: your whole query is unnecessarily over-complicated. Do you really need these hints, `LEFT JOIN`s and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: apologies, I had summations on other columns which I removed when pasting in the query. That was why I have the left joins and groups.

The coalesce came as result of running the query through TOADs new SQL optimiser.

Thanks again

Comment: Could you please post the whole query before it was optimized by `TOAD`?

Comment: thanks. I tried that and had a syntax error. think it is something on the copy but much appreciated.